# Python H5pyのインストール失敗

Tags: python

●Pythonの全くの初心者です。PC関連の専門的な知識もあまりありません。
インターネット上のサイトに投稿させて頂くのも初めてです。
失礼がありましたら、ご容赦下さい。

●業務上、pythonを使用してHDF5形式のファイルを取り扱う必要が生じ、そのため、ネット上の情報を参考にして、PCにPython, numpyをインストールし、その後h5pyのインストールを試みましたが、失敗します。

●各インストール用ファイルは、個別にPythonのホームページからダウンロードし、コマンドプロンプトを使用してインストールしました。

●numpy, h5pyはコマンドプロンプト画面で

```sh
python -m pip install (インストール用ファイルパス)
```

で実行し、numpyだけはインストール出来ました、

＜PC＞
Surface Pro 4, 64bit
＜OS＞
Windows 10

＜インストール済＞
Python 3.6.4 (python-3.6.4-amd64.exeを使用してインストール)
numpy 1.14 (numpy-1.14.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whlを使用してインストール)
＜インストールに失敗＞
h5py 2.7.1 (h5py-2.7.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whlを使用)

●h5pyのインストールに失敗した際に表示された情報は以下の通りです。
(コマンド)

```sh
python -m pip install d:\users\user1\Downloads\h5py-2.7.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

(表示された情報)

```
Processing d:\users\user1\downloads\h5py-2.7.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six (from h5py==2.7.1)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/six/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement six (from h5py==2.7.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for six (from h5py==2.7.1)
```

●どうすれば、h5pyをインストール出来るか、すいませんがご教示願えますでしょうか？
なお、自動的にh5pyを取得するコマンドと思われる `pip install h5py` を実行しましたが、社内のネットワークの関係(Proxy?)で失敗します。

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCを会社のネットワークから外して、iPhoneテザリングで再度、pip install h5pyをトライしたところ、無事h5pyのインストール出来ました。お騒がせしました。

Haru様、どうもありがとうございました。